# Not working in Mozilla firefox and works fine in chrome $('input[data-type="choise"]').change(function()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Iam working with online test portal developing its working fine with chrome but the problem is it not working woth mozill.My code is as follows and it works fine in chrome and not working in the mozilla firefox Suggest me the alternative or solution for.

input[data-type="choise"] is not working

```
        <script>
( document ).ready(function() {
                                $('input[data-type="choise"]').change(function() {
              var Question = $(this).attr('name');
              var Checked = $(this).attr('value');
                 y++;
              if(Checked=="0"){

              }else{
                  x++;


              }
              $('#score').replaceWith("<span id='score'><input type='hidden' name='score' id='score' value='"+ x +"' /> <input type='hidden' name='totalquestions' id='totalquestions' value='"+ y +"' /></span>");
                alert('Selected Choise for ' + Question + ' is ' + Checked+ 'and score is'+ x);

            });
            });
            </script>

        <div class="time">
        <label> Remaining Time </label> <span id="timer"></span>
        </div>
        <?php 
         include('connection.php');
        $test=$_SESSION["testnum"];
        $query=mysql_query("select * from questions where Testno='$test' order by Id ASC"); 
        if($query==true){  ?>
        <form id="scoretarget" name="formsubmit" action="congrasulations.php" method="POST">
        <span id="score"><input type="hidden" name="score" id="score" value="" />
        <input type='hidden' name='totalquestions' id='totalquestions' value="" />
        </span>
        <hr class="hr">
        <?php $id=1;
        While($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){ ?>
            <?php 
            $questionnum=$row['Questionno'];
            $question=$row['Question'];
            $ans=$row['Answer'];
            ?>
             <div class="question">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">

            <label class="control-label form-inline">
            <?php echo $questionnum?>
            </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-11 quest-left">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label form-inline">
            <?php echo $question;?>
            </label>

            </div>
            <fieldset>
         <input type="radio" data-type="choise" name="q<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?php if($ans=="Option A"){ echo"1";}else{echo"0";} ?>"><span> <?php echo $row['Option1'];?></span><br>
         <input type="radio" data-type="choise" name="q<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?php if($ans=="Option B"){ echo"1";}else{echo"0";} ?>"><span> <?php echo $row['Option2'];?></span><br>
         <input type="radio" data-type="choise" name="q<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?php if($ans=="Option C"){ echo"1";}else{echo"0";} ?>"><span> <?php echo $row['Option3'];?></span><br>
         <input type="radio" data-type="choise" name="q<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?php if($ans=="Option D"){ echo"1";}else{echo"0";} ?>"><span> <?php echo $row['Option4'];?></span><br>
             </fieldset>
          </div>

          </div>
            </div><br>
          <?php ++$id;} ?>


          <input type="submit" name="proceed" value="proceed" class="btn btn-info pull-right">


          </form>

        <?php  } else{?>

        <div class="question">
            <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12">
        <h4 style="text-align:center; color:red;"> Question Paper is not updated  </h4>
        </div></div></div>
        <?php }

        ?>
              </div>
```

Comment: please use this $("input[data-type=choise]")

Comment: You have a typo here `( document )` but i guess just in question. Now, you have to define 'not working'? Error in console? How do you debug it? Anyway, your selector works on FF for sure, so i'm not sure what makes you think it is your issue?!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
( document ).ready(function() {
                                $('input[data-type="choise"]').click(function() {
              var Question = $(this).attr('name');
              var Checked = $(this).attr('value');
                 y++;
              if(Checked=="0"){

              }else{
                  x++;


              }
              $('#score').replaceWith("<span id='score'><input type='hidden' name='score' id='score' value='"+ x +"' /> <input type='hidden' name='totalquestions' id='totalquestions' value='"+ y +"' /></span>");
                alert('Selected Choise for ' + Question + ' is ' + Checked+ 'and score is'+ x);

            });
            });
            </script>

        <div class="time">
        <label> Remaining Time </label> <span id="timer"></span>
        </div>
        <?php 
         include('connection.php');
        $test=$_SESSION["testnum"];
        $query=mysql_query("select * from questions where Testno='$test' order by Id ASC"); 
        if($query==true){  ?>
        <form id="scoretarget" name="formsubmit" action="congrasulations.php" method="POST">
        <span id="score"><input type="hidden" name="score" id="score" value="" />
        <input type='hidden' name='totalquestions' id='totalquestions' value="" />
        </span>
        <hr class="hr">
        <?php $id=1;
        While($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){ ?>
            <?php 
            $questionnum=$row['Questionno'];
            $question=$row['Question'];
            $ans=$row['Answer'];
            ?>
             <div class="question">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">

            <label class="control-label form-inline">
            <?php echo $questionnum?>
            </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-11 quest-left">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label form-inline">
            <?php echo $question;?>
            </label>

            </div>
            <fieldset>
         <input type="radio" data-type="choise" name="q<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?php if($ans=="Option A"){ echo"1";}else{echo"0";} ?>"><span> <?php echo $row['Option1'];?></span><br>
         <input type="radio" data-type="choise" name="q<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?php if($ans=="Option B"){ echo"1";}else{echo"0";} ?>"><span> <?php echo $row['Option2'];?></span><br>
         <input type="radio" data-type="choise" name="q<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?php if($ans=="Option C"){ echo"1";}else{echo"0";} ?>"><span> <?php echo $row['Option3'];?></span><br>
         <input type="radio" data-type="choise" name="q<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?php if($ans=="Option D"){ echo"1";}else{echo"0";} ?>"><span> <?php echo $row['Option4'];?></span><br>
             </fieldset>
          </div>

          </div>
            </div><br>
          <?php ++$id;} ?>


          <input type="submit" name="proceed" value="proceed" class="btn btn-info pull-right">


          </form>

        <?php  } else{?>

        <div class="question">
            <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12">
        <h4 style="text-align:center; color:red;"> Question Paper is not updated  </h4>
        </div></div></div>
        <?php }

        ?>
              </div>
```

Comment: Change 
$('input[data-type="choise"]').change(function()   TO
 $('input[data-type="choise"]').click(function()
its working fine with chrome and firefox